# how can pass post param to url with webview?

Tags: android, post, webview

I am using below code to open website page in my android application that need send post parameters with it,

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
String url = "https://xxxxx.com/payment/";
 try{
        String postData ="token="+URLEncoder.encode(token,"UTF-8")+
                "&language="+URLEncoder.encode("fa", "UTF-8");

        webview.postUrl(url, postData.getBytes());
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
       //
    }
```

I can't understand what is wrong in this code? some times it does not show any things and in other times it does not send parameters correctly.

I have been testing the url and the parameters with this form in web site and it is work without any problem

```
<form id="form" action="https://xxxxx.com/payment/" method="post">
        <label>Token:</label><input type="text" id="token" name="token" value="$token" />
        <label>language:</label><input type="text" id="language" name="language" value="fa" size="5px" />
        <input type="submit" id="btnPymnt" value="payment" name="btnPymnt" />
</form>
```

but in android application i have problem.

Comment: how do you add your `webview` to layout? in posted code you are creating new instance without attaching to layout. also: `try{}catch` is redundant for `postUrl`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved problem by this code:

```
    public void call(String Token){
    webView.setWebViewClient(new NameActiviy.myWebClient());
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            try {
                String postData = "token=" + URLEncoder.encode(Token, "UTF-8") +
                        "&language=" + URLEncoder.encode("fa", "UTF-8");
                url = "https://xxxxxx.com/payment/";
                webView.postUrl(url, postData.getBytes());
            }
            catch(IOException ioe){
                //
            }
}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```